# Not able to to display the third slideshow on my html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I basically copied code of multiple slideshows from w3schools https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_multiple

The first two slideshows are working just fine but, the third slideshow I tried adding afterwards isn't displaying at all and neither the images seems to be loading on the inspection page.

I wanted images to load lazily as well

Please help me with this.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
    var slideIndex = [1,1];
    var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2", "mySlides3"]
    showSlides(1, 0);
    showSlides(1, 1);
    showSlides(1, 2);
    
    function plusSlides(n, no) {
      showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
    }
    
    function showSlides(n, no) {
      var i;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
      if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}    
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
         x[i].style.display = "none";  
      }
      x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";  
    }
```

```css
    * {box-sizing: border-box}
    .mySlides1, .mySlides2 {display: none}
    img {vertical-align: middle;}
    
    /* Slideshow container */
    .slideshow-container {
      max-width: 1000px;
      position: relative;
      margin: auto;
    }
    
    /* Next & previous buttons */
    .prev, .next {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      width: auto;
      padding: 16px;
      margin-top: -22px;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 18px;
      transition: 0.6s ease;
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    /* Position the "next button" to the right */
    .next {
      right: 0;
      border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    }
    
    /* On hover, add a grey background color */
    .prev:hover, .next:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      color: black;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h2 style="text-align:center">Multiple Slideshows</h2>
    
    <p>Slideshow 1:</p>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides1">
        <img loading="lazy" src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    
      <div class="mySlides1">
        <img loading="lazy" src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    
      <div class="mySlides1">
        <img loading="lazy" src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    
    <p>Slideshow 2:</p>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides2">
        <img loading="lazy" src="img_band_chicago.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    
      <div class="mySlides2">
        <img loading="lazy" src="img_band_la.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    
      <div class="mySlides2">
        <img loading="lazy" src="img_band_ny.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides3">
        <img loading="lazy" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/313CFbI-YjL._SX512_.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    
      <div class="mySlides3">
        <img loading="lazy" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41zOmaUKehL._SX512_.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    
      <div class="mySlides3">
        <img loading="lazy" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41ePfTRprsL._SX512_.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    
      <div class="mySlides3">
        <img loading="lazy" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/31bjKqlul6L._SX512_.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    
      <div class="mySlides3">
        <img loading="lazy" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/311m3klP3oL._SX512_.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    
      <div class="mySlides3">
        <img loading="lazy" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/315hICqUx0L._SX512_.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 2)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 2)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third slideshow is not functioning because when `plusSlides` is called on the third slideshow, it references index 2 of the array `slideIndex`. However, you've defined the array only up to index 1: `var slideIndex = [1, 1];`. Changing this line to `var slideIndex = [1, 1, 1];` fixes your third slideshow.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the variable slideIndex only have two positions:

```
var slideIndex = [1,1];
```

For solve the problem, add one position more to the array:

```
var slideIndex = [1,1,1];
```

Greetings.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Andreu! I'm giving your answer a "useful" vote as a welcome to the site!