# Running 2 slideshows in the same page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to run 3 slideshows on one page, I tried copying the code but it wasn't successful. I'm using a W3 slideshow. Also, I want to make the Next & previous buttons like in this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow  Please help me

Here is the code:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
.mySlides {display:none;}
```

```html
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<body>

<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%">

  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share your attempt to duplicate the slideshow.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Among US! W3Schools has separate tutorial for [displaying multiple slideshows](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_multiple) on a single page. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69197033/not-able-to-to-display-the-third-slideshow-on-my-html) for a code example where I helped another user troubleshoot displaying three slideshows.